# Bootstrap 5.1 - Duda sobre responsive

Tags: html, bootstrap

adjunto esta pregunta por que tengo una duda sobre algo que esta pasando en mi barra de navegacion y no le encuentro respuesta , adjunto una foto y parte del codigo para que puedan ver por su cuenta a ver si me pueden dar una idea

Es responsive mi navbar , la unica duda es que al jugar con los tamaños del navegador me encuentro esos casos donde queda cortada y trate de pensar el motivo no logro sacarlo

Imagen 1
[image: ejemplo1]

[image: ejemplo2]

Desde ya muchas gracias gente
Espero que entiendan la duda , cualquier cosa edito la publicacion

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to- 
         fit=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <title>NEU - Nueva Editorial Universitaria</title>
  <!-- Favicon-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/cropped-logo- 
         32x32.webp" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/cropped-logo- 
         180x180.webp" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/cropped-logo- 
         192x192.webp" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/cropped-logo- 
         270x270.webp" />
  <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap- 
        icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Google fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
         family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap 5.1)-->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
  <!-- Font Awesome-->
  <link href="/Public/assets/FontaWesome-6.0.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <!--------------------------------------INICIO BARRA DE NAVEGACIÓN------------------------------------>
  <div class="fixed-top" style="background-color: #30408B;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #30408B;">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" title="Inicio">
            <img src="/Public/assets/img/logo1.webp" width="250" class="d-inline-block align-top pb-2" alt="Logo NEU">
          </a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="#" title="Inicio">INICIO</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="institucional.html" title="Institucional">INSTITUCIONAL </a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="subSecretaria.html" title="SubSecretarÍa General">SUBSECRETARÍA</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="catalogo.html" title="Catálogo">CATÁLOGO</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="comercializacion.html" title="Comercialización">COMERCIALIZACIÓN</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class=" row col-md-4 col-sm-8 d-flex ms-5">
              <div class="col-2 pl-1 pl-2">
                <a class="nav-redes" href="https://www.facebook.com/NEU-nueva-editorial-universitaria-347188832343695/" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="bi-facebook fs-3"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2 pl-1 pr-2">
                <a class="nav-redes" href="https://twitter.com/NeuUnsl" title="Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="bi-twitter fs-3"></i></a>
              </div>
              <!--div class="col-4" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;">                  
                                    <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Buscador">
                                    </div-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Intenta agregando stilo al img:

```
style="width: 100%; min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px; max-height: 150px;"
```

he cambiado el src del logo para efectos de prueba, ver:

```html
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>




<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to- 
         fit=no" />
  <meta name="description" content="" />
  <meta name="author" content="" />
  <title>NEU - Nueva Editorial Universitaria</title>
  <!-- Favicon-->
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/cropped-logo- 
         32x32.webp" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/cropped-logo- 
         180x180.webp" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/cropped-logo- 
         192x192.webp" />
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="assets/img/favicon/cropped-logo- 
         270x270.webp" />
  <!-- Bootstrap icons-->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap-icons@1.5.0/font/bootstrap- 
        icons.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Google fonts-->
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css? 
         family=Lato:300,400,700,300italic,400italic,700italic" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <!-- Core theme CSS (includes Bootstrap 5.1)-->
  <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/aos@next/dist/aos.css" />
  <!-- Font Awesome-->
  <link href="/Public/assets/FontaWesome-6.0.0/css/all.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</head>

<body>

  <!--------------------------------------INICIO BARRA DE NAVEGACIÓN------------------------------------>
  <div class="fixed-top" style="background-color: #30408B;">
    <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark" style="background-color: #30408B;">
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="index.html" title="Inicio">
            <img style="width: 100%; min-width: 100px; min-height: 100px; max-height: 150px;" src="https://logodownload.org/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/burger-king-logo-1-1.png" width="250" class="d-inline-block align-top pb-2" alt="Logo NEU">
          </a>

          <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarScroll" aria-controls="navbarScroll" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                            </button>

          <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarScroll">
            <ul class="navbar-nav">
              <li class="nav-item active ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="#" title="Inicio">INICIO</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="institucional.html" title="Institucional">INSTITUCIONAL </a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="subSecretaria.html" title="SubSecretarÍa General">SUBSECRETARÍA</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="catalogo.html" title="Catálogo">CATÁLOGO</a></li>
              <li class="nav-item ms-5"><a class="nav-link" href="comercializacion.html" title="Comercialización">COMERCIALIZACIÓN</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class=" row col-md-4 col-sm-8 d-flex ms-5">
              <div class="col-2 pl-1 pl-2">
                <a class="nav-redes" href="https://www.facebook.com/NEU-nueva-editorial-universitaria-347188832343695/" title="Facebook" target="_blank"><i class="bi-facebook fs-3"></i></a>
              </div>
              <div class="col-2 pl-1 pr-2">
                <a class="nav-redes" href="https://twitter.com/NeuUnsl" title="Twitter" target="_blank"><i class="bi-twitter fs-3"></i></a>
              </div>
              <!--div class="col-4" style="margin: 0 0 0 0;">                  
                                    <input class="form-control" id="myInput" type="text" placeholder="Buscador">
                                    </div-->
            </div>
          </div>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</body>

</html>
```